# Logging tcp conversations with pcap

Tags: c, networking, tcp, pcap

I am a new user and relatively new to C / C++ so bear with me:)

I am developing a real time network data sonification application for a university project, that synthesises sounds for packets captures by a simple packet sniffer using libpcap.

Right now it is able to do this, but the sheer volume of traffic often means my audio synthesis can't keep up.

I need to be able to log and track tcp conversations as Wireshark is able to do, so that I can synthesise sounds for an entire tcp connection rather than each individual packet. I have looked into the Wireshark source code, but I really can't figure out how it implements its functionality!

Does anyone have any insight into tcp conversation tracking with libpcap, even at a very simplistic level:)

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some good examples at these sites

http://www.programming-pcap.aldabaknocking.com/codesamples.html

http://recursos.aldabaknocking.com/libpcapHakin9LuisMartinGarcia.pdf

http://www.tcpdump.org/pcap.html

http://yuba.stanford.edu/~casado/pcap/